# Facebook Graph API to find connectness

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find out how two arbitrary users are connected (n-degree connectedness) using the current Facebook graph API?

If that is not possible, is it possible to find a connected chain from me to an arbitrary user?

Comment: There is an app that promises to do just that but seems to be down https://www.facebook.com/DegreesApp

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get a connected chain with the API. The only thing that is possible is to check if you (= the authorized user) are friends with another user who is using the App too. And you would need to authorize users with `user_friends`, of course.

You can call `/me/friends` and see if the other user is in there.